# Ejercicio con Busqueda recursividad

Tags: java-8

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Cierto tipo de bomba, requiere de un detonador para activarse. Estas bombas están hechas de tal forma, que solo su detonador puede activarlas. Esto se realiza haciendo que tengan el detonador y el enchufe de éste diferente para cada bomba.

Tienes en tu poder 20 bombas con sus 20 respectivos detonadores. Sin embargo, no sabes cuál detonador corresponde a qué bomba y necesitas saberlo. No puedes comparar ningún detonador con ninguna bomba, ya que para esto requerirías enchufarlos y activarías la bomba. Tan solo puedes comparar los detonadores entre sí, y las bombas entre sí.

Toma en cuenta que en las localidades de la `1` a la `20` están los tamaños de los enchufes de las bombas y de la `21` a la `40`, los tamaños de los detonadores.

Ya lo he resuelto de la siguiente manera (recursivamente):

```
public class DetonadorAndBomb {

    public static void bomb(int []a,int m,int n){
        if(a[m]==a[n+1]){
            System.out.println(a[n+1]);
            if(!(m==(n+1))){
                n=1;
                bomb(a,m+1,n);
            }

        } else{
            bomb(a,m,n+1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num[] = {1,3,3,1};
        bomb(num,0,1);
    }
}
```

Y en la consola resulta:

> 1
>
> 3
>
> 3

Se supone que no debe de imprimir el ultimo valor.

Comment: ¿Puedes aclarar lo de las localidades?, porque en el código no se muestra ninguna.

Comment: *Se refiere a las posiciones del vector*

Comment: Ah, ¿entonces se debe comparar la posición 1 con la 2, la 2 con la 3, la 3 con la 4, ..., la 19 con la 20; y después la 21 con la 22, la 22 con la 23, la 23 con la 24, ..., la 39 con la 40? ¿O es de la otra forma: la 1 con la 21, la 2 con la 22, la 3 con la 23, ..., la 20 con la 40?

Comment: debo comparar posiciones de para encontrar que detonador le corresponde a que bomba y la posicion la estoy tomando como referencia por ejemplo arreglo[] = {1,2,3,3,1,2}; debo decir la posicion **1** (interruptor 2) le corresponde la posicion **5** (bomba 2) y asi sucesivamente no se si me explico es como el segundo caso de su comentario.

Comment: Excelente aclaración, ahora para ver si pude entender, fijate la posible solución que publiqué recién, en forma recursiva, como pide el enunciado, porque la solución más sencilla es usando dos bucles `for`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ver si entendí:

> a [ ] = {1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2}

Salida:

> A la posicion **0** (*interruptor* 1) le corresponde la posicion **4** (*bomba* 1)
>
> A la posicion **1** (*interruptor* 2) le corresponde la posicion **5** (*bomba* 2)
>
> A la posicion **2** (*interruptor* 3) le corresponde la posicion **3** (*bomba* 3)

### Posible solución recursiva:

```
public class DetonadorAndBomb {

    public static void bomb(int []a,int m,int n)
    {
        int t = a.length,    // Tamaño del vector.
            h = t/2;         // Posición donde comienza la segunda parte del vector.
        // Control para que m se mantenga en la primera mitad del vector.
        if (m<h)
        {
            if(a[m]==a[n])    // Se encontró una coincidencia.
            {
                System.out.format("A la posicion %d (interruptor %d) le corresponde "+
                                  "la posicion %d (bomba %d)\n", m, a[m], n, a[n]);
                bomb(a,m+1,h);    /* La posición m ya tuvo coincidencia con
                                     la posición n, entonces se sigue buscando,
                                     para las siguientes posiciones, comenzando en m+1 */
            }
            else if (n < t-1)     /* No hubo coincidencia, entonces se controla que
                                     haya posiciones disponibles en la segunda parte
                                     del vector para seguir buscando posibles
                                     coincidencias para la posición m */
                bomb(a,m,n+1);
            else                  /* No hubo coincidencia y no quedan posiciones
                                     disponibles en la segunda mitad del vector,
                                     por lo que la búsqueda debe continuar desde m+1. */
                bomb(a,m+1,h);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num[] = {1,2,3,3,1,2};

        bomb(num,0,num.length/2);
    }
}
```

***[Código disponible con mensajes de depuracíon para ver de manera visual el funcionamiento de la función recursiva.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/fYDlq9ITvhXB9T46)***

Comment: Exactamente; Es algo tonto lo que voy a preguntar, aparte de decirte gracias por el apoyo, de que otra forma te puedo devolver el gesto?

Comment: Está bien, si te sirvió la solución propuesta, con las ***"gracias"*** es suficiente. Además, si lo prefieres, tienes la opción de ***"[aceptar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)"*** la respuesta.